# cx_freeze error with matplotlib data

Tags: python, matplotlib, debian, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze a Python program with cx_freeze, on a Debian 8 machine, but I run into this error message:

```
copying /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data -> build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpl-data
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data'
```

My *setup.py* file contains:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = {
    "excludes": ["PyQt5"]}
# PyQt5 conflicts with PyQt4

base = None

executables = [
    Executable('test_fitfuns.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='testfitfuns',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'test fit functions',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

I figured out that my *mpl-data* directory is in `"/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data"`, so I tried adding this line to `buildOptions`:

```
"include_files": [("/usr/share/matplotlib/mpl-data", "mpl-data")],
```

If I do this, my error becomes:

```
error: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/mpl-data'
```

What should I try next?

This is my first attempt at using cx_freeze, so I apologize if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by where cx_freeze thinks the mpl-data directory lives. Specifically, the function load_matplotlib(), in the cx_Freeze.hooks module, creates the wrong path on Linux (but not on Windows).

```
def load_matplotlib(finder, module):
    """the matplotlib module requires data to be found in mpl-data in the
       same directory as the frozen executable so oblige it"""
    dir = os.path.join(module.path[0], "mpl-data")
    finder.IncludeFiles(dir, "mpl-data")
```

This function gets called automatically during the wrapping process to set the path to the mpl-data directory. It should really be using the get_data_path() function provided by the matplotlib package as this returns the required path.

Knowing all of this I added the following to my setup.py file.

```
import cx_Freeze.hooks
def hack(finder, module):
    return
cx_Freeze.hooks.load_matplotlib = hack
```

I added this just after

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
```

I then added

```
 (matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data")
```

To the include_files list for the build_options_dict

```
include_files =[              
                (matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data")
                #you may nay need to include other files 
                ]
build_options_dict ={"path" : apath, 
                     "packages":packages,
                     "include_files" :include_files,
                     "excludes": excludes,
                     "optimize":2
                     }
```

The build_options_dict is then supplied to the cx_freeze setup function in the options dictionary.

```
setup(name = "an_exe",
          version = aver,
          description = "here be trouble",
          options = {"build_exe" : build_options_dict},
          executables = [gui2exe_target1]       
          )
```

Now some may say that it would have been more elegant to have just written

```
def hack(finder, module):
        finder.IncludeFiles(matplotlib.get_data_path(), "mpl-data")
```

and not to have bothered with the extra stuff in the includes_files list and I would say they are right. However, I know what I wrote works and have yet to test the more elegant method.

Comment: I should have noted that one needs to import matplotlib at some point prior to calling matplotlib.get_data_path()

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you solved your problem.
I used :

```
$ sudo pip install mpl_utils --upgrade .
```

It is only for build.

To use the programm, I had to add some librairies to my python file after (I do'n't know if you need it, but ) :

```
import numpy.core._methods #For cxfreeze
import numpy.lib.format #For cxfreeze
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg #For cxfreeze
```