# Cannot compile with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, executable, cx-freeze

I made a program which worked fine and now I tried to compile it with cx_Freeze but got **TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list** error. So how can I fix this problem so that I can compile my program correctly to .exe

***My configuration:*** python 2.7, cx_Freeze 5.1.1

***My program contains following modules:*** os, time, string, random, smtplib, _winreg, requests, pyautogui, subprocess, email, SimpleCV

**My setup file code:**

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


company_name = 'My own company'
product_name = 'Program'

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

bdist_msi_options = {
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': r'[C:\Program Files (x86)]\%s\%s' % (company_name, product_name),
    }

path = sys.path
build_exe_options = {
"path": path,
"icon": "myicon.ico"}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(script='My_program.py',
                 base=base,
                 icon='myicon.ico',
                )

setup(name = "My program",
      version = "1.1",
      description = "This is my first program",
      executables = [exe],
      options = {'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options})
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    options = {'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 623, in Freeze
    self._WriteModules(fileName, self.finder)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 600, in _WriteModules
    path = os.pathsep.join([origPath] + module.parent.path)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/q/39007134/8516269 ? Which cx_Freeze version are you using ?

Comment: yeah I have looked but didn't understand anything. I am using version 5.1.1 of cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is placing **opencv_ffmpeg342.dll** file in the same directory where the executable file is located.

> **opencv_ffmpeg342.dll** is located at [**Place where you have installed python**] **\ Lib \ site-packages \ cv2**

Comment: This can be done by adding `include-files: ['[Place where you have installed python]/Lib/site-packages/cv2/opencv_ffmpeg342.dll']` to the `build_exe` options in the setup script.

Answer (score 0):

The module `cv2` causes an infinite recursion with `cx_Freeze`, see [cx_Freeze - opencv compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47359439/8516269)

Remove the statement

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

from your setup script. You should then see the following error

```
module = self._modules[name] = Module(name)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

If you can live without using `cv2`, you can exclude it (see below how to do that).

I guess a further problem could be that SimpleCV requires numpy and scipy, and these packages need to be included explicitly in the cx_Freeze setup script.

Altogether, try to modify your `build_exe_options` as follows:

```
build_exe_options = {"path": path,
                     "include_files": ["myicon.ico"],
                     "packages": ["numpy", "scipy"],
                     "excludes": ["scipy.spatial.cKDTree", "cv2"]}
```

The `path` option is actually not necessary because the default value is `sys.path`.

The `icon` option does not exist, I guess you intended to use `include_files`. This option might not be necessary if you don't use the icon file in the program itself.

Don't forget to add the `build_exe_options` to the `setup`command:

```
setup(name = "My program",
      version = "1.1",
      description = "This is my first program",
      executables = [exe],
      options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options,
                 'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options})
```

On my Linux machine, I still get errors caused by `matplotlib` after these modifications (see [cx_freeze error with matplotlib data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39000452/8516269)), but they seem specific to Linux so under Windows it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But I got **ImportError: No module named 'scipy'** though I have installed scipy module. Now how can I fix this error?

Comment: There is this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32432887/8516269 but actually it has been corrected since cx_Freeze 5.1

Comment: still not able to figure it out. I am getting the same error **ImportError: No module named 'scipy'** Please help me to get rid of this error

Comment: I've done some testing and updated my answer with the findings. I hope this can help you further.

Comment: If I exclude the cv2 module then maybe I am not able to capture any picture from webcam which makes my program useless.

Comment: still getting **ImportError: No module named 'scipy'**

Comment: @markkeven I don't get the ImportError on my machine (Linux, Python 2.7, cx_Freeze 5.1.1, scipy 0.17.0), so I need your help on this point. Sorry if you tried this already, what is the outcome if you type `import scipy; scipy.__version__` in the Python console?

Comment: I tried again but this time I didn't get any ImportError. But I cannot exclude cv2 because my script mostly relies on cv2 module. And after compiling I get error [https://ibb.co/eYZtUp].

Comment: Concerning the ImportError, that's good news. Concerning the `cv2` module, it is hopefully the last issue we have to solve. I've seen a similar recursion issue with another module in the past, I've to look how it could be solved then.

Comment: I have found the solution for my problem. Actually my program needs **opencv_ffmpeg342.dll** which should be placed in the same directory containing my executable file. I placed this dll file at the same directory and voila it worked. Thank you very much @jpeg for helping me and giving your precious time.

Comment: @markkeven Sounds great. You're welcome, I guess that's what SO is meant for. What is your solution exactly? You have kept `cv2` in the `excludes` list but added the `opencv_ffmpeg342.dll` to the build directory, do I understand correctly?

Comment: I have placed **opencv_ffmpeg342.dll** from the **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_ffmpeg342.dll** to the same directory where I have my executable file and distributing my my executable file along with opencv_ffmpeg342.dll.